# Using PHP cURL to POST data on /oauth2/access_token and GET data as jSON

Tags: php, json, api, curl, oauth-2.0

I has follow step on [Path API](https://path.com/developers/docs) about how to Authentication User. In the tutorial auth process, user is begin to redirect to the following URL and prompt to grant access:

https://partner.path.com/oauth2/authenticate?response_type=code&client_id=THE_CLIENT_ID

And after that, server will give response as authorization **code** via URL Address (i have complete this step and got the **code**).

As from docs explain, Code is should be exchanged for an access token using **/oauth2/access_token** as long with Client ID and Client Secret (get access_token)

But i don't have any clue how to POST data via cURL to the server, i has try so many **curl_setopt()** option and combination, but it still give me a nothing.

From the Docs, Request is look like this:

```
POST /oauth2/access_token HTTP/1.1
Host: partner.path.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: <LENGTH>

grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=CLIENT&client_secret=SECRET&code=CODE
```

And cURL format like this:

```
curl -X POST \
     -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
     -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
     -F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
     -F 'code=CODE' \
     https://partner.path.com/oauth2/access_token
```

And server will give response like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 CREATED
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: <LENGTH>

{
    "code": 201,
    "type": "CREATED"
    "reason": "Created",
    "access_token": <ACCESS_TOKEN>,
    "user_id": <USER_ID>,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform a POST request in PHP with cURL, you can do something like:

```
$handle = curl_init('https://partner.path.com/oauth2/access_token');
$data = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code', 'client_id' => 'CLIENT', 'client_secret' => 'SECRET', 'code' => 'CODE');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$resp = curl_exec($handle);
```

You can then use `json_decode($json_encoded)` to get an associative array from the server response.

Comment: I'm already using that way and reTest again, but it still not work for me :( still give me a blank pages although i'm already using echo/print_r/var_dump from $resp variable

Comment: Is it just not working, or do you get any error messages? Do you get any response from the server at all?

Comment: No, i'm not get any response from server, it just not working :( but when i test using Postman it work fine

Comment: you have to use `http_build_query($data)` otherwise the `content-type` won't be set to `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have figured this out yet or not since i see it was from awhile ago, but I just had this problem and this is how I figured it out.

```
$code = $_GET['code'];
$url = 'https://YourPath/token?response_type=token&client_id='.$client_id.'&client_secret='.$client_secret.'&grant_type=authorization_code&code='.$code.'&redirect_uri='.$redirect_uri;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);

$exec = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($exec);
if (isset($json->refresh_token)){
global $refreshToken;
$refreshToken = $json->refresh_token;
}

$accessToken = $json->access_token;
$token_type = $json->token_type;
print_r($json->access_token);
print_r($json->refresh_token);
print_r($json->token_type);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

addition to Fox Wilson answer:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: You should add this as a comment to the alleged answer by @Fox Wilson

Comment: I was going to, but got "You must have 50 reputation to comment"