# How to use curl to make Oauth oauth_token and oauth_client_id

Tags: php, curl

Example Authorization with Postman Authorization:

```
oauth_token="AQDSADSAAA****************", 
oauth_client_id="5c9ASDASD********"
```

The same thing I need to repeat in `curl` in `php`, how can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using PHP cURL to POST data on /oauth2/access\_token and GET data as jSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416209/using-php-curl-to-post-data-on-oauth2-access-token-and-get-data-as-json)

Comment: It really depends on the API. They can either be passed in post or headers. If it's in post, you can check the above answer.

Comment: No, i using get request

Comment: I want use in headers

Comment: Then use `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, depending on your API : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426047/correct-way-to-set-bearer-token-with-curl

Comment: Your "example" isn't really an example of anything - are these just variables that you're using in your Postman request somewhere? *Where* are you putting them? Note also that [Postman can generate PHP code for your request](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/)